# How to build Image Editor using HTML5 and Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, raphael

I am building a web application and for this I am building a basic Image Editor using `HTML5` and `Raphael js`. I have implemented some features like:

1. Resize
    Flip horizontal and/or vertical
    Drag

Some more features I need to implement are :

1. Crop
    Undo/Redo
    Changing background colour and opacity.

I am mainly looking for crop and undo functionality. Can anyone help me to achieve this using `RaphaelJs` and `HTML5`?

My Code:

```
var r, c, d;

    var paper = Raphael("editor", 600,450);


    var canvas = document.getElementById('editor');
    canvas.style.backgroundColor='gray';

    $scope.current;


    var someFunction = function(e) {
        e.data('dragged', false);
        e.drag(dragmove, dragstart, dragend);

        for(var i in elements) {
            var thisShape = elements[i];
            var ft = paper.freeTransform(thisShape,{draw:['bbox']});
            ft.hideHandles();
            thisShape.click(function(){
                paper.forEach(function(el) {
                    if(el.freeTransform.handles.bbox != null)
                        el.freeTransform.hideHandles();
                });

                this.freeTransform.showHandles();
            });
        }
    };

    function dragmove(dx, dy, x, y, e) {

        this.transform(this.current_transform+'T'+dx+','+dy);
    }

    function dragstart(x, y, e) {
        this.current_transform = this.transform();

    }

    function dragend(e) {
        this.current_transform = this.transform();
    };


    var elements = [];

    $scope.raph = function () {

        c= paper.circle(40,40,40).click(function() {
            someFunction(this);
            $scope.current= this;
        });
        r = paper.rect(50, 60, 100,100,25).click(function() {
            someFunction(this);
            $scope.current= this;
        });

        d = paper.rect(70, 60, 100,100,25).click(function() {
            someFunction(this);
            $scope.current= this;
        });

        elements.push(c,r,d);

        c.attr({
            fill:'red',
            cursor:'pointer'

        });
        r.attr({
            fill:'green',
            cursor:'pointer'
        });

        d.attr({
            fill:'blue',
            cursor:'pointer'
        });

    };

    $scope.back = function () {
        $scope.current.toBack();
    }
    $scope.front = function () {
            $scope.current.toFront();

    }
    $scope.clear = function () {
        paper.clear();
    };
    $scope.flips = function () {
        $scope.current.rotate(180);
    };

    //function for cloning element
     $scope.clones = function () {
          var n =   $scope.current.clone();
         n.attr("x",$scope.current.attr("x")+100);
         $scope.current = n;

         elements.push(n);
         n.click(function() {
             someFunction(this);
         });
        };

    $scope.changing= function (e) {

        $scope.opacity=event.target.value;

        if($scope.current != null){
            $scope.current.attr({
                opacity:$scope.opacity
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide a more concise question/answer, with a concise example illustrating the problem.

Comment: I want to crop image using Raphael js. I am not finding a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but you need to define actually what you want with a crop. A new image, somethingto save, or just so it appears cropped like with a clip, or something else. Is it an svg image, any image or whatever.

Comment: ya. I want to crop image and replace it with original image.

Comment: How does that make sense? If you crop an image and replace it with the original image nothing changes...?

Comment: I mean replacing original image with cropped image. I ma still not getting a way to do it with the help of raphael js.

Comment: I wouldn't think too much about Raphael at this stage as odd as it sounds. You haven't mentioned what the image is. Is it svg or something like png/jpeg, as Raph is primarily dealing with SVG. I would start off with just trying to crop an image without dragging or anything of the rest of the code. I suspect you may want html5/canvas or a library to do it.

Comment: It is jpeg/png type Image. I dont want to use any jquery plug-ins  to crop the image. But i am not able decide which JavaScript library I should use.

Comment: If not jQuery, what about [darkroom](http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/)?

Comment: @RodrgoDEla It is based on the awesome FabricJS library to handle images in HTML5 canvas. Can I use it for SVG?

Comment: I am looking Crop Tool similar to this, http://fashupp.com/editor/webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** just use Fabric.js  http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/, although you'll probably need to add Darkroom http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/ for cropping.

---

Some suggestions for RaphaelJS:

- resize:  http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform `c.transform('S1.5,1.5')`
- flip: resize with a negative scale in either direction (`S-1,1`)
- drag: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag, also consider set overloads like http://wesleytodd.com/2013/4/drag-n-drop-in-raphael-js.html
- changing colors and stuff: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr
- undo -- you'll have to save a list of operations/previous states to reverse?
- crop -- most likely you'd create the UI in raphael using a mask/overlay (layers: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.toBack) to send instructions to a server-side API to handle the heavy work.  You can manipulate raster images in the browser, but if people are uploading photos it could quickly overload the memory limitations (think: unedited 12MP photo)

Check out stuff like Sketchpad http://ianli.com/sketchpad/ or the commented Darkroom http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/ for ideas.

You can always try exploring the sourcecode for existing web editors, like Google+... (that was mostly a joke).